# C++ Forward Declaration confusion

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with forward declaration, well, I'm confused about everything.
I have 3 classes that depend on each other. For example:

- ClassA depends on ClassB and ClassC
- ClassB depends on ClassA
- ClassC depends on ClassA
- ClassA and ClassC have only static methods and static members

I want to know how can I use forward declarations in such a manner to avoid circular dependencies.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean "ClassA and ClassC are static", in C++, there is no "static class"

Comment: @CuiHeng they are composed of static methods and static members

Comment: "Depends on" in what manner, exactly? Details matter.

Comment: You can use, for instance, before any definition, `class ClassA; class ClassB; class ClassC;` but that will just make any possible problem visible later on. It's not a silver bullet. I would start redesigning the classes so you avoid the circular dependencies from the design itself, not just using forward declarations.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B;
class C;

class A{
public:
    static B instanceOfB;
    static C instanceOfC;
    static void foo(){
        cout << "A static foo called"<< endl;
    }
};



class C{
   static A instanceOfA;
};

A C::instanceOfA = A();


class B{
    A instanceOfA;
};

B A::instanceOfB = B();


int main(){
    cout << "main run"<<endl;
    A::foo();
    return 0;
}
```

1st, it is a bad design when class depends on each other.
2nd, this kind of depends should doesn't mean you have to hold the object of the class, instead, if this dependent is complicated, you need to use a "pointer" to the object instead of holding the object. "Pointer to object" means compiler will not require the full prototype of that class.

Comment: I have redesigned all my classes, and now it works without problems! Thanks everyone!